# A program to print "Hiss" If the input string contains two consecutive occurrences of the letter "s" and "no hiss" , if it doesn't

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.11

We need to write a piece of code to print "Hiss", If the `input string` contains two consecutive occurrences of the letter `s` and print "No hiss" if it doesn't. What I've written so far is this:

```
word = list(input())

for i in range(len(word)):
    if word[i] == 's':
        if word[i+1] == 's':
            print("hiss")
        else:
            print("no hiss")
```

The problem is that I get this error message : `IndexError: list index out of range`.

I think the problem is related to this part of the code `word[i+1] == 's'` but I can't really understand the reason, here, in this line, I'm trying to compare an item, with the next item so what is the problem and how can I fix this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you *do* choose to iterate, then you can't print `no hiss` just because the *first* `s` you find isn't followed by another `s`. You have to wait until the loop completes without printing `hiss` before you can decide to print `no hiss`.

Comment: You can fix the code shown by un-indenting the last two lines so that the `else` part is part of the `for` loop, not either `if` statement.

Comment: @kindall, Thanks for the tip, you're right , there's no need to iterate over it. Bu , what is the problem with  [i + 1] in the code? why do I get that error?

Comment: Eventually, `i` will be the largest valid index for `word`, at which point `i + 1` is, by definition, *not* a valid index.

Comment: @Pantea You need to do `range(len(word) - 1)` so that `i + 1` doesn't go beyond the length of the list. Also, you should put `break` after `print("hiss")` and unindent the `else` clause to the same level as the `for` statement.

Comment: @blackbrandt Nothing happens then. Because that doesn't happen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For example, your string word looks like `hiss` and the length of it is 4.
For is iterating from 0 to 3 and when you add +1, you're trying to access 4 element which doesn't exist (cause' index of all iterable objects starts from 0) [Here](https://www.stechies.com/fix-list-index-out-range-python/) you read about `out of range` exception

```
word = input()

if 'ss' in word:
   print('Yes')
else:
   print('No')
```

In this code you trying to find substring 'ss' in word, and if it's in `in` keyword will return true else return false

Comment: Correct, but I think `if 'ss' in word` would be more idiomatic than using `count()`.